# How can I use Groovy Postbuild to force a job to success?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to force a unit test job to success if the main build returned a failed exit code.  Here is how I configured it and it is not working (see screenshot).  Does anyone know any reason why this shouldn't work?   In this example I just want to show that a failing job can be changed to a passing job by a groovy postbuild step. [The plugin doc implies that this should work.](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin)

1. The main build runs a batch script with "EXIT 1" to fail the build.
2. A Groovy Postbuild step runs manager.buildSuccess() in an attempt to force the build to success (but it fails to do so with no error).

[image: my screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I found a discussion about that problem on [jenkins-JIRA](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12010).

As a workaround it is proposed to use reflection to make the build successful:

```
manager.build.@result = hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS
```

This workaround doesn't work for me, but perhaps it can help you

Answer (score 0):

Install Groovy Post Build Plug in.
Then add the below Groovy Script.

```
manager.build.@result = hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS
```

Uncheck the Use Groovy Sandbox. This worked for me.